# Finding the volume of a right cylinder in terms of full surface area and a variable

Tags: solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

Let S be the full surface area of a right cylinder. Let H be the height of the cylinder and r be the radius of it's base. Let m = H-r. Find the volume V of the cylinder in terms of S and m.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried by substituting H with r+m. However I can't find an equation to express r with m.

Comment: As S = 2pi x r(H + r) and m = H - r use these 2 equations to eliminate H and solve for r by quadratic equation formula in terms of m and S.  Put the solution back to find H in terms of m and S.  Substitute r and H (both in terms of m and S) to the V equation.  The answer is in terms of m and S though very ugly.